# Moving applications from one computer to another

Tags: windows, installation, operating-system, windows-installer, ms-office

My laptop has MS Office 2013 and I have a desktop computer has MS Office 2010, and I want to transfer ms office 2013 from my laptop to desktop computer, how can I do that?

Comment: You have pen drive? You use Google  drive or box.com?

Comment: Flash memory better

Comment: This would probably fit better on [su].

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean moving the actual application.

As the application you want to reinstall is Microsoft Office, you may find some useful info on the Microsoft website: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Download-and-install-or-reinstall-Office-2013-on-a-PC-or-Office-for-Mac-2011-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1

In more general terms, moving an application is not as easy as it sounds to do manually. Applications rely on files and registry entries in multiple locations. On top of that, there may also rely on other deployed components such as services. Your best bet is to use an application to do that:

- PCmover Professional, which costs $29.95 or £20.95 (half price offer)
- Zinstall’s WinWin ($119).
- EaseUS offers a free version of Todo PCTrans Free 8.0, which will transfer two applications. The unlimited version, Todo PCTrans Professional, costs $49.95.

This article has more info about it: https://www.theguardian.com/technology/askjack/2015/sep/17/move-files-programs-to-new-pc-windows-10

Another option is to look for the MSI installer of the application you want to transfer in the MSI cache of the source computer (C:\Windows\Installer - this article describes how to find the right file: http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/334-identifying-cached-msi-packages-in-cwindowsinstaller-without-opening-them), transfer it to the destination and execute it. This can work but you will most likely need the serial key for the application.

Bear in mind that you should also consider the legality of transferring an application from one computer to another. It is very likely that having the application installed on both computers, requires you to have 2 licenses.